# OpsHub migration select team project fails with object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, exception, reference, opshub

I installed the latest version of OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility this week from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2/file/132237/7/OVSMU-V1.1.0.001.exe.

Install completed successful and I am able to select our TFS server and VSO server locations but get `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` error at the Select Team Projects screen. Suggestions?

**Error:**

```
2014-12-08 07:16:55,855 [1] ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.ProjectSelectionViewModel.loadProjectWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in e:\OVSMUBranch\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\ProjectSelectionViewModel.cs:line 312
```

Comment: Hi Pam. Sorry to hear that. Can you send us the log files located at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs to ovsmu@opshub.com. From error,its not able to load all project from either TFS or VSO.
We will check logs and update proper answer here.

Comment: Hi Pam, we are still awaiting on your logs. Can you try the following and see if that solves your issue. Close all instances of Visual Studio
Open Task Manager and check if any TFS Services are running.  Select each of them and click on End Process Tree
Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents and folders
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
(Don't Delete Cache folder, remove the content of folder)

Comment: I have the same issue; I have emailed the contents of the logs folder to the above mentioned email address.